# save the name of VM to array using powershell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

This command saves list of VM to array.

```
[string]$arrayVM = Get-VM | select Name
```

When it refers to the first element of the array: `$arrayVM[0]`

I get the name of VM, but this value look like: `@{name=MACHNINE_1_NAME}`

I expected only the same name: `MACHNINE_1_NAME`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[string]$arrayVM = Get-VM | select Name
$arrayVM[0].Name
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the `-ExpandProperty` parameter to your `Select-Object` command. What this does is expands the value of the specified property and passes that down the pipeline instead of restricting the properties of the current object to be passed down the pipeline. Right now you are passing a `Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine` object with only the `Name` property intact. This will instead pass a `string` with the value of the `Name` property.

```
$arrayVM = Get-VM | select -expand Name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[string]$ArrayVM = (Get-VM | Select-Object -Property Name).Name
```

Comment: using `[string[]]` instead of `[string]` will give you an array.